# What does this '这样真的容易累成胖子' means?

Tags: translation

这样真的容易累成胖子

"Getting easily tired like this is (making me) turn fat?"

I don't really know how to understand this sentence, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The sentence is illogical at all, unless it could combine with more context to fill up a joke. Like the one: 我应该多吃点，否则我都没有力气去减肥了。

Answer (score 1):

> 这样真的容易累成胖子

Getting tired like this (making me) turn fat easily.

这样真的容易... > ... like this really easily ...

累成胖子  > Getting tired makes fat.

verb + 成 + noun >  doing something (verb) then produces the result (noun)

BTW: What sort of tired thing making people fat other than thin?

Comment: Probably, getting tired of eating?

Comment: @pbeta [:emoji-smiled-with-tears]

Answer (score 1):

Some article claims tiresome desk job make people gain weights.

So this term only applies to any tiresome tasks/works that don't involve physical work out.